# How to debug wifi connection?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)

I am using Ubuntu's `Network Manager` to connect to a local wifi router. My problem is, that it often disconnects without any visible reason (router is on, internet connection seems to be working, wifi diodes are blinking). I mostly have to disable wifi from Network Manager, enable it again to get wifi connecting again.

Plus I am often experiencing `Network Manager` trying to connect to my wifi, trying several times but then giving up.

I even tried an external usb-wifi card, but with the very same results.

My question is:

**How can I debug this? Which logs should I read to see what is really happening when all of these errors occur - so I can post them here and see how to proceed?**

Answer (score 14):

To be precise, this post answers my question: https://askubuntu.com/a/61547/78383:

To debug your wifi-connection, you use `dmesg` to output the logs your wifi card produces.