# Were is the C drive in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: wireless

I have been having issues with my wifi and a friend told me that if i copy the C drive to a memory stick and boot my system from it i can reinstall ubuntu 13.04 (which is what i have).

Is this true? If so where is the C drive?

Also I did a system test and under wifi it says that i am missing packages (doesn't say which one/s).

I have done updates and all that include updating through terminal, and the wifi is still not working properly, one minute its fine the next it refuses to work, so I am trying to reinstall and see if that fixes the problem.

I am using Dell inspiron mini 10.

I also have a red triangle at the top of my screen that says, `The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer active. Please update manually by selecting show updates from the indicator menu, and watching for failing repositories`

I have updated but this still shows up and the wireless still fails to work unexpectedly (1 minute its fine, the next its not). The red triangle aslo takes time to show up after turning on laptop and usually shows up after 2 hours of the laptop being on.

Comment: Reinstalling is extremely unlikely to solve your problem, it is likely your wireless card is incompatible or that you need to install additional packages. Please identify your hardware. http://askubuntu.com/questions/210017/how-to-debug-wifi-connection . c: is a windows thing, Linux uses / and /dev/sda , see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: Also, edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (run this in a terminal, of course).

Answer (score 2):

C:/ drive is more of a Windows thing and Linux doesn't name it's disk partitions in this manner. Instead, you ought to be looking for label names such as "computer", "xGB Filesystem", etc. Or if you're using tools like parted, GParted and such you can view your partitions as "/dev/sda1" and so on. Find the volume which matches your hard disks or partitions space and you can probably assume that's the one you're looking for. Personally I don't believe that you can boot an OS purely because you've backed up your drive but if there's a way to do it I'm not going to argue.